# How can i create these worn edges?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, edges, procedural

I've been trying to create worn edges following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lYseMQDkPAI&t=375s&ab_channel=thesparkofart,
but can't seem to achieve same results. This node setup doesn't "capture" all the edges, and certainly not the ones i'd like it to. In the top pictures it only work on concave edges, but on the bottom it kind of goes for the convex ones but in a strange manner - it either only select on of the edges of each face (like either bottom or top one - not both) or it also marks the faces itself. That's the main issue.

Another problem is with the mudgrave texture, wich, when multiplied with these edge-nodes, plasters texutre spots all over the model - not on the edges like in tutorial.

Final photo is result of this method: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JMMy-xqrwdw&feature=youtu.be&t=156&ab_channel=LifeKILLED

If that matters i have bevel modifier on that model - but disableing it doesn't help.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like your mesh is really low-poly, the pointiness node is really limited when your mesh density is low. You might want to try this technique instead https://youtu.be/JMMy-xqrwdw?t=156 (bevel + normal dot product)

Comment: @Gorgious Wow. Of Course! That's ingenious.

Comment: It seems like a better method overall but produces same effect. It only applies to some edges of each face, not all of them - will add photo in the question